# Specify inner components in react-admin Fields

Tags: react-admin

Is there a way to specify the innermost components for a react-admin Field (For instance for the PictureField to override the 'img' tag with another MyImgComponent)?

Or do I have to create a whole new MyPictureField duplicating almost all of the code?

In the specific problem with the 'img' tag I would like to replace it with an Img component that handles authentication so that only images accesible by the logged in user can be shown in the PictureField.

Comment: Perhaps this is the solution to the above problem: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authorization.html#restricting-access-to-fields-and-inputs

Comment: @MaxAlex no. not really. Even if the field is presented to specific users, the browser makes an http GET request to the api server without authorization header and still the user cannot see the image